# Generating a random number in a custom range

Tags: go, random

I have go script that starts on "localhost:8080/1" with a  **previous** and **next** links I need to add **Random** link  with custom range that I can change like:

- small numbers like 100 to 200 "localhost:8080/100 - 200" and
- even to big number like: "16567684686592643791596485465456223131545455682945955"

So:

```
// Get next and previous page numbers

previous := new(big.Int).Sub(page, one)
next := new(big.Int).Add(page, one)
random :=????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the package [`crypto.rand` Int()](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Int) function, which does support `big.Int` (as opposed to the [`math.rand` package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/))

See [this article](https://medium.com/orbs-network/big-integers-in-go-14534d0e490d#cecf) (and its [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/KBBYNwh0klK)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "crypto/rand"
)

func main() {
    var prime1, _ = new(big.Int).SetString("21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495617", 10)
    // Generate random numbers in range [0..prime1]
    // Ignore error values
    // Don't use this code to generate secret keys that protect important stuff!
    x, _ := rand.Int(rand.Reader, prime1)
    y, _ := rand.Int(rand.Reader, prime1)
    fmt.Printf("x: %v\n", x)
    fmt.Printf("y: %v\n", y)

}
```